# Converting Character Response to "N" over a dataset

Tags: r

To start off, and example Dataset :

```
x <- data.frame(v1=1:5,v2=1:5,v3=1:5,
v4=c("Bob","Green","Curley","Banana","No"), 
v5=c("Hello","This question is awful, Mad",NA,"Help","Me"))
```

I've got a large dataset with a multitude of numeric and character variables (survey data). These responses vary greatly in content and length; the order these variables are in matter, as well.  I'm trying to find a way to select all of the character variables in my dataset, and then set any responses to the letter "N"/"Another item" (while leaving the NA values intact).

With the help of other users in the community, I'm able to fill all of these character variables with NA or "N", etc. :

```
x[,sapply(x, is.character)] <- "N"
```

But, I would really like to be able to retain those NA values present within the data - Something like this (I'm not very proficient with the apply functions just yet) :

```
x[ #Contains ANY Text# ,sapply(x, is.character)] <- "NA"
```

I haven't found anything that will allow me find any and all text within a row/column? It appears something like GREP only works with specific character strings to my knowledge.  I'm also unsure of my formatting with the aforementioned function is correct, so please let me know if I'm making an error in placing my #Contains ANY text# argument.

Thanks in advance All!

Comment: I would `ch <- sapply(x, is.character); x[, ch][x[, ch] != "N"] <- 'N'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.frame` is a list so its columns can be changed using `lapply`.

Here we can subset `x` to the character columns, and then `lapply` over them replacing non-NA values with whatever we want.

```
x <- data.frame(v1=1:5,v2=1:5,v3=1:5,
                v4=c("Bob","Green","Curley","Banana","No"), 
                v5=c("Hello","This question is awful, Mad",NA,"Help","Me"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # your original data.frame had factors
x
#   v1 v2 v3     v4                          v5
# 1  1  1  1    Bob                       Hello
# 2  2  2  2  Green This question is awful, Mad
# 3  3  3  3 Curley                        <NA>
# 4  4  4  4 Banana                        Help
# 5  5  5  5     No                          Me

is_char_col <- sapply(x, is.character)
is_char_col
#    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Use `replace`:

```
x[is_char_col] <- lapply(x[is_char_col], function(k) replace(k, !is.na(k), "N"))
x
#   v1 v2 v3 v4   v5
# 1  1  1  1  N    N
# 2  2  2  2  N    N
# 3  3  3  3  N <NA>
# 4  4  4  4  N    N
# 5  5  5  5  N    N
```

If the replacement logic is actually more complicated, you could modify the anonymous function inside `lapply`.

Comment: I didn't notice the original came in as factors in my fictional little dataset, so thanks for that, as well.  I applied your solution to my real dataset and it worked out **perfectly**. I'll have got go into your code a little bit more to really understand all of the steps. But, this worked and I appreciate it greatly.  I also was not aware I could subset and replace like that! There is still much to learn, I suppose! Thanks, again

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using a generic function as mentioned by @effel.

```
x <- data.frame(v1=1:5,v2=1:5,v3=1:5,
            v4=c("Bob","Green","Curley","Banana","No"), 
            v5=c("Hello","This question is awful, Mad",NA,"Help","Me"),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x <- data.frame(lapply(x, function(i) if(is.character(i)) ifelse(!is.na(i), "N", i) else i))
```